# Why are functional representations of systems important in physics or computational physics?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, variational-principle, numerical-method

This was an addendum to a previous question I asked, but I figured I should make it it's own discussion.

Assuming I am able derive a functional representation for *any* dynamical system (dissipative, nonlinear, fractional, PDE, ODE, discontinuous, etc), why would such a result or capability be useful? What are some abstract consequences to such a capability? What are some practical (computational, design, etc) consequences?

In essence, what are functionals used for in practice?

Keep in mind, the functionals I'm referring to might be of non-standard form (i.e, non-conservative systems), for example:

Any system with that is a potential or conservative will have a functional representation as:
$$
F[\mathbf{x}]=\int^{t}_0\left(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\mathbf{x}}(\tau)^2-V(\mathbf{x}(\tau))\right)\,\text{d}\tau
$$

Where taking the first variation of this functional yields the dynamics of the system, along with a condition that effectively states that the initial configuration should be similar to the final configuration (variation at the boundaries is zero).

*But*, you can construct other functionals for non-conservative systems, such as this convolutional functional:

$$  
F[\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * D(\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{Ax}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}'(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
With $\mathbf{A}$ symmetric and $\mathbf{x}(0)$ being the initial condition, and:
$$
[\mathbf{f}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{g}]=\int^{t}_0 \mathbf{f}^{\text{T}}(t-\tau)\mathbf{g}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$

If we take the first variation and assume **only** that the initial variation is zero, the functional is stationary with respect to:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}= \mathbf{Ax}(t)
$$

Point being that one should also consider the implications of functionals which are not inner product based.

Comment: In a nutshell: Computational advantage: Lagrangian descriptions are not, like the Newtonian laws, bound to the particular choice of spatial coordinates, you can choose generalized coordinates that make the E-L equations look nicer than Newtons laws. Aesthetical advantage: The principle of least action is nice, and Noether's theorem is powerful.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: You helped me with my last question, now this one! Just wanted to say thank you, as well.

As for the coordinate change: I see what you mean, if it's an invariant principle, it should be invariant with respect to the reference frame.

An added comment: I know that variantional principles are important in FEA, are there other numerical applications in which they are, or can be useful (anyone can answer this).

Comment: Another comment: given some functional for a system, is it possible to use it in the data sciences? How can someone fuse the two ideas? Given information about the state, can a variational formulation be used for parameter identification? (I'm not sure whether this is the right stackexchange for such a question, some advice on where to post this would also help)